# Make element move out of container

Tags: html, css

Example HTML/CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi libero veritatis dolores facere, eaque aspernatur, magnam repellendus eveniet, ullam magni accusamus accusantium itaque a illo totam vitae. In, earum quos.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If there any chance to move left edge of `.element` to left edge of `.wrapper`, while its right edge stays snapped to right edge of `.container`. In other words, I want to override left margin of `.container` by adding some rules to `.element`. I've tried something like:

```
.element {
  margin-left: -100%
}
```

But it moved the whole element, as I expected.

Comment: Hmm...it really depends on why you need to do this. If you could clarify the reason it might help. At the moment this sounds like an [**XY Problem**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Actually, this IS a reason. Designer put all content inside a container of a certain width. But one block of content is snapped width its left edge to body, while its right edge still snapped to container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could position the element absolutely *relative* to the `.wrapper`, and then use `calc()` to determine what `50% - 200px` is:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6oakas4j/) - borders added for demonstration purposes..

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.element {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: calc(50% - 200px);
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="element">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi libero veritatis dolores facere, eaque aspernatur, magnam repellendus eveniet, ullam magni accusamus accusantium itaque a illo totam vitae. In, earum quos.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, must be the best solution avaliable. Although it won't work with `max-width`, there is no other solutions without javascript, I guess. Thanks Josh Crozier.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a position, but you will need javascript to calc the correct width.

```
.element {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

JQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var w = ($(".container").outerWidth()/2) + $(".container").width();
    $(".element").width(w);
});
```

Comment: Not the best option, as for me. With jQuery involoved And I'd calculate negative margin instead. I'm trying to avoid `position: absolute` as it breaks height of container element. 
Josh Crozier's solution is preferable for me. But thanks anyway.